# High ping latency in local wireless environment

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, ping

Tried to ssh a local server via wifi, but got a very high latency.
Then I tried to ping the server while the data looks very strange.
Sometimes it's pretty good while sometimes has a very high ping latency.
BTW, the router is Linksys WRT1900ACS with OpenWrt 4.4.14 running on it.

[Ping data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LzCl.png)

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with wireless as opossed to cables is there may be (unknown number of) other users of same medium, slowing you down.  Most common example is retransmissions due to interference from other wifi users on the same or nearby wireless channels.

Solution might be to change your AP wifi channel to some less used, if possible.

Comment: Use a free tool like acrylic wifi to scan your wifi environment and change your channel to the least used. Also make sure your router isn't overheating and monitor the CPU load on it to make sure its not saturated. Either can cause temporary performance degradation.  Link https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/